# Which registers should be preserved in MIPS?

Tags: assembly, mips

in MIPS which registers should be preserved on stack to prevent data loss. (T-S-A-V-RA REGISTERS)

Comment: It probably depends on what ABI you are using ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my [MIPS reference sheet](http://www.cs.uah.edu/~gcox/613/GreenCard1.JPG), the following registers are callee-saves (have to be preserved by the called function) while the rest are caller-saves (aren't required to be preserved by a called function):

- `$s0 - $s7` (registers 16-23), the saved temporaries
- `$gp` (register 28), the global pointer
- `$sp` (register 29), the stack pointer
- `$fp` (register 30), the frame pointer
- `$rp` (register 31), the return address

(Note, `$rp` is listed as not saved in [other versions of the cheat sheet](https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs61c/resources/MIPS_Green_Sheet.pdf).)

**Source:** [Computer organization and design](http://books.google.dk/books?id=3b63x-0P3_UC)

Comment: This answer is very much incomplete. The good answer would not be simple, and would require MIPS ABI information. For instance, $gp is not callee saved for o32 ABI, but caller saved.

Comment: Why save the stack pointer? You could always just do another `addi` to it, right?

Comment: $ra isn't preserved across calls: https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs61c/resources/MIPS_Green_Sheet.pdf

Comment: @Neel Thank you. My book at home actually lists it as saved, and is the same edition as mentioned on yours. I have updated the link to point to a working version, and mentioned that there are two versions.

Comment: @new123456: Not literally saved to memory and restored, just that it has to have the same value before and after the caller's JAL instruction.  How you achieve that is up to you.  (e.g. don't touch it in the first place).  I like the terms "call-preserved" vs. "call-clobbered", because they don't imply anything about actually saving.  (And they differ by more than one letter).  volatile / non-volatile also work, except that `volatile` is a keyword in C and C++ with a totally different meaning, so I worry that it could be slightly confusing to people that don't already understand the concept.